# Google AppEngine Vendor Deploy (composer)

Tags: php, google-app-engine, composer-php, vendor

Vendor folder couldn't deploy in App engine.

I installed `composer install` locally and works find in localhost

But, to deploy

```
gcloud app deploy app.yaml
```

Sadly, vendor folder couldn't deploy in my App Engine. Locally, I have vendor folder from composer:

[image]

But when I deploy with `gcloud app deploy app.yaml` In App engine source code, there is no vendor folder:

[image]

index.php

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

app.yaml

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:

- url: /(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$|vendor$))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$|vendor$))
  application_readable: true

- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /fonts
  static_dir: fonts

- url: /src
  static_dir: src

- url: /vendor
  static_dir: vendor

- url: /vendor/composer
  static_dir: vendor/composer

- url: /vendor
  script: vendor

- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1

- url: /image
  static_dir: image

- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```

Comment: What does "Sadly, vendor folder couldn't deploy in my App Engine" mean? And why don't you put all information here, but link to some blog post?

Comment: Is your `vendor` dir side-by-side with `app.yaml` (it should be) or one directory above? I can't really tell from your picture. If it's not move/symlink/copy it side-by-side. Only what's inside the directory containing `app.yaml` is deployed.

Comment: @Nico Haase. because of my level,  I couldn't put image here. That's why I link some blog post. Now, I don't know how but Dan Cornilescu edited it.
I meant that I have vendor folder and app.yaml in same directory. But vendor folder couldn't upload with   `gcloud app deploy app.yaml`.
When I check my deployed source in app engine, there was not vendor folder.
I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thank you @DanCornilescu. From your answer I got clue. vendor dir is side-by-side with app.yaml. So I just moved vendor inside the app.yaml directory

Comment: Hi Emma, Can you tell me where did you go to view the deployed source on AppEngine? I cant seem to find it. Secondly, I am running into the same problem as yours. Can you tell me how did you fix it? Where did you move your vendor folder? Thanks

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53459196/4495081

Answer (score 0):

Only what's present in the app directory (which is the one where the `app.yaml` file is located, in your case `xoxo`) is deployed. But your `vendor` directory appears located one directory above.

If so that explains why it's not deployed. You need to move/symlink/copy it inside the `xoxo` directory.

Comment: I did exactly what you told me to do. It works. Thank you for your answer :)