# Appengine app deployment is not uploading some folders

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have an app deployed on AppEngine.
When I test the app locally, everything works fine.
I have done composer install and the "vendor" folder exists.

When I view the source, i can see that some folders are not uploading.
This is my folder structure on local drive:

[image: local folder structure]

I deploy using this code:

```
gcloud app deploy --promote --stop-previous-version app.yaml
```

The deployed structure looks like this:

[image: Deployed app]

As you can see, only dialpad_research folder is uploaded.
My app.yaml file is like this:

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

env_variables:

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(appcache|manifest))
  mime_type: text/cache-manifest
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(appcache|manifest))

- url: /dialpad_research/(.*\.(appcache|manifest))
  mime_type: text/cache-manifest
  static_files: dialpad_research/static/\1
  upload: dialpad_research/static/(.*\.(appcache|manifest))

- url: /(.*\.atom)
  mime_type: application/atom+xml
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.atom)

- url: /(.*\.crx)
  mime_type: application/x-chrome-extension
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.crx)

- url: /(.*\.css)
  mime_type: text/css
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.css)

- url: /(.*\.eot)
  mime_type: application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.eot)

- url: /(.*\.htc)
  mime_type: text/x-component
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.htc)

- url: /(.*\.html)
  mime_type: text/html
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.html)

- url: /(.*\.ico)
  mime_type: image/x-icon
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.ico)

- url: /(.*\.js)
  mime_type: text/javascript
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.js)

- url: /(.*\.json)
  mime_type: application/json
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.json)

- url: /(.*\.otf)
  mime_type: font/opentype
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.otf)

- url: /(.*\.rss)
  mime_type: application/rss+xml
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.rss)

- url: /(.*\.safariextz)
  mime_type: application/octet-stream
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.safariextz)

- url: /(.*\.(svg|svgz))
  mime_type: images/svg+xml
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(svg|svgz))

- url: /(.*\.swf)
  mime_type: application/x-shockwave-flash
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.swf)

- url: /(.*\.ttf)
  mime_type: font/truetype
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.ttf)

- url: /(.*\.txt)
  mime_type: text/plain
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.txt)

- url: /(.*\.unity3d)
  mime_type: application/vnd.unity
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.unity3d)

- url: /(.*\.webm)
  mime_type: video/webm
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.webm)

- url: /(.*\.webp)
  mime_type: image/webp
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.webp)

- url: /(.*\.woff)
  mime_type: application/x-font-woff
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.woff)

- url: /(.*\.xml)
  mime_type: application/xml
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.xml)

- url: /(.*\.xpi)
  mime_type: application/x-xpinstall
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.xpi)

# audio files
- url: /(.*\.(mid|midi|mp3|wav))
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(mid|midi|mp3|wav))

# windows files
- url: /(.*\.(doc|exe|ppt|rtf|xls))
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(doc|exe|ppt|rtf|xls))

# compressed files
- url: /(.*\.(bz2|gz|rar|tar|tgz|zip))
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(bz2|gz|rar|tar|tgz|zip))

# index files
- url: /(.*)/
  static_files: static/\1/index.html
  upload: static/(.*)/index.html

- url: /dialpad_research/api/(.+\.php)$
  script: dialpad_research/api/\1

- url: /vendor/(.+\.php)$
  script: vendor/\1

# site root
- url: /
  static_files: static/index.html
  upload: static/index.html


- url: /static
  static_dir: static


- url: /dialpad_research/static
  static_dir: dialpad_research/static

# dialpad root
- url: /dialpad_research.*
  static_files: dialpad_research/static/index.html
  upload: dialpad_research/static/index.html

# portfolio redirect
- url: /portfolio/.*
  static_files: static/red.html
  upload: static/red.html

# G2 redirect
- url: /g2.*
  static_files: static/red.html
  upload: static/red.html

# Blog redirect
- url: /blog.*
  static_files: static/red.html
  upload: static/red.html

# SSDESIGN redirect
- url: /ssdesign.*
  static_files: static/red.html
  upload: static/red.html

# Colours redirect
- url: /colours.*
  static_files: static/red.html
  upload: static/red.html
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `static` directory is expected to be missing on GAE because it's handled via a `static_dir` handler, so by default it's not uploaded together with the app code. If you want it uploaded together with the app code you need to set the `application_readable` for it. From [Handlers element](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/appref#handlers_element):

> **application_readable**
>
> Optional. Boolean. By default, files declared in static file handlers
>   are uploaded as static data and are only served to end users. They
>   cannot be read by an application. If this field is set to true, the
>   files are also uploaded as code data so your application can read
>   them. Both uploads are charged against your code and static data
>   storage [resource quotas](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Code).

The same applies to all individual files served via `static_file` handlers.

Things are different for the `vendor` directory - no static file/dir references it.

I can't yet see a reason for `vendor` not being uploaded from the info from your post. Things you can try:

- increase the verbosity of your deployment command using the `--verbosity` [global option](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy#GCLOUD-WIDE-FLAGS), it *should* mention which files/directories are being skipped and why.
- if you have a [`.gcloudignore` file](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore) in your service check its content
- use a directory name different than `vendor` - just in case that particular name is handled differently for whatever reason - just a wild guess, in case the reason for skipping the directory isn't uncovered by the increased verbosity

Comment: Thanks for your reply Dan. I understand static not visible here. The vendor folder was not created by me, it gets created automatically. So are you suggesting I name it differently and then change my code? In that case, is it a good idea to rename system generated folder by Composer?

Comment: Just as a test, to see if that has anything to do with it missing. It doesn't even have to work, you just want to see if it's deployed.

Comment: Oh got it. Let me try it out.

Comment: That seems to work. I changed the folder name to "sender" and that gets uploaded. The vendor does not.

Comment: IT WORKS :) The .gcloudignore was stopping vendor folder from being uploaded... Even though the problem is solved, can someone explain how that ignore file got added and how did it specify to not upload vendor?